# Extract derived 3D scaling from a Sprite to set to a 2D billboard

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, matrix, scaling

I am trying to get the ***derived* position** and **scaling** of a 3D Sprite and set them to a 2D Sprite.

I have managed to do the first part like this:

```
        var p:Point = sprite3d.local3DToGlobal(new Vector3D(0,0,0));
        billboard.x = p.x;
        billboard.y = p.y;
```

*But I can't get the scaling part correctly.* I am trying this:

```
        var mat:Matrix3D = sprite3d.transform.getRelativeMatrix3D(stage); // get derived matrix(?)
        var scaleV:Vector3D = mat.decompose()[2]; // get scaling vector from derived matrix
        var scale:Number = scaleV.length;
        billboard.scaleX = scale;
        billboard.scaleY = scale;
```

...but the result is apparently wrong.

PS. One might ask what I am trying to achieve. I am trying to create "billboard" 3D sprites, i.e. sprites which are affected by all 3D transformations except rotations, thus they always face the "camera".

Comment: I think you can have more answers on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation says that you get the vector correctly, but its coefficients don't seem to be added together to form a single length value. Try first an unscaled sprite, and check if you're receiving a sqrt(3) value as its length. If yes, then you should use 0th element of the vector as X scale, and 1th as Y scale. I'm not sure what to do with 2nd element (in this case it'll be a Z scale, either divide both scales by it, or multiply by it). Hope that helped.

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing of what you suggest works. 1st, I am using a non-self-scaled sprite, but the matrix returned isn't sqrt(3) length. In fact, while the sprite rotates/moves around in 3D space, the returned vector length varies. Multiplying or diving x and y with z won't help either.

Comment: If your sprite is just not scaled at all, what are the values of scaling vector?

Comment: The scaling Vector is like : Vector3D(0.3204055726528168, 0.43539050221443176, 0.2867351770401001). This is I suppose because we are talking about the "global" transformation matrix and not the local one (which by itself is useless)...

Comment: Weird thing that this scaling vector is shorter than 1.0, and it's obviously not a vector of separate values. Sorry, can't help any further.